# Google BigQuery: Add date to table name when creating a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am writing a query I am planning to schedule using Big Query UI.

I would like to add a _TABLE_SUFFIX to this table which is equal to CURRENT_DATE.

How could I achieve that?

This is the query I am working on:

```
IF 
  today != DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
THEN 
  CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.tablename_<insert_current_date_here>`
  AS
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE() as today;
END IF;
```

Comment: FYI, related discussion on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/eyt9vb/google_bigquery_add_date_to_table_name_when/. My advice is to use a PARTITIONED table instead for even better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery supports [a template system](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#templating_system) for destination table names in scheduled queries. To add the current date to the table name, use the provided template syntax. For example, `tablename_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}` would output `tablename_YYYYMMDD`.

[image: bigquery scheduled query settings]

Answer (score 4):

**Update (2023-01-09):** I think Samuel's approach using an official templating solution here is ideal.

The best bet would be to generate the query dynamically, and then execute it statically.

This could be done using something like python.

from datetime import datetime

```
def get_query():
    return '''IF 
    today != DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    THEN 
    CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.%s`
    AS
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE() as today;
    END IF;''' % str(datetime.now())
```

Comment: Agree, I regularly do this, also started using Jinja as well, see https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-dynamic-sql-using-jinja-template-5c1332317960

Answer (score 0):

You could (whether you should is another debate) create dynamic table names via BQ's [SQL procedural language](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language) capability, specifically the [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate) statement.

e.g.

```
DECLARE today STRING DEFAULT STRING(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY));

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.tablename_%s` AS
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() as today
""", today);
```

For more also see [towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dynamic-sql-in-bigquery](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dynamic-sql-in-bigquery-8c04dcc0f0de).

Note you might also now get error location issues with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` , if so try changing/checking your `Processing location in Query Settings`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157622/error-of-location-with-execute-immediate-on-bigquery)