# Error of location with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

when I use the command:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://archivage_base/archive1_@EXPORT_DATE*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT * FROM `base-042021.campagnemakers.makerlocal`
"""
using current_date() as EXPORT_DATE
```

I have this error:

> Not found: Datasetbase-042021:campagnemakers was not found in location US at [2:1]

I don't understand why because i don't have the error without the command EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. My location is EU.

Comment: If you running this in UI - try to change `Processing location` in `Query Settings`

Comment: Thank you, it solves the problem.

Comment: thanks Mikhail, I've been banging my head to the wall

Comment: When I do this on UI, it works fine. But I run into a similar problem when I execute the query through java. Even though I sepcifically set the location to EU. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

This solution from Mikhail Berlyant worked for me.

> If you running this in UI - try to change Processing location in Query
> Settings.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32297131)