# Create new files from multiple export query data in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run multiple export statements in bigquery like this

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://bucket/folder/*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT field1, field2 FROM mydataset.table1 ORDER BY field1 LIMIT 10
```

The problem is that I don't want to overwrite new files, but instead I want new files to be created only if the query returns something.

I've tried changing the `uri` to `gs://bucket/folder/*1.csv` but this is creating an empty file (which I don't want).

I've also set the `overwrite` parameter to `false`; this results in `Invalid value: overwrite option is not specified and destination is not empty. at [109:1]`

Any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may try and consider below approach.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT(
    "EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(uri='gs://your-bucket-bucket/your-folder/file_",
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F-%T", TIMESTAMP(Current_TIMESTAMP()), "UTC"),
    "_*.csv', format = 'CSV', overwrite = true, header = true, field_delimiter = ';') AS SELECT field1, field2 FROM your-dataset.table1 ORDER BY field1 "
)
```

This approach concatenates current timestamp to your filename so that it will serve as a unique identifier of file names and will create a new one if your query returns something.

**Sample output on my Bucket:**
[image]

In addition, if you experience a `location error` when executing the above query, the posted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157622/error-of-location-with-execute-immediate-on-bigquery) will solve the problem.

Comment: Let me try this!

Comment: @BigqueryQuestioner if you find my answer helpful, you may accept/upvote it so that others may know that you've been sufficiently helped.

Comment: This doesn't work because as soon as you go ahead and add anything else to the `uri` other than just the `*`, it will go ahead and output to the file.

So why do I put a number next to the `*`? This is because the query is not able to export multiple files to the same bucket, unless you present a different `uri`. But specifying a `uri` means that something outputs, even if there's nothing to export.

Comment: One way to get around this is to use `IF` statements and see if the select query returns something. If nothing is returned, then we can go ahead and export.

My only concern is that I don't want to execute these queries twice (once to check and once to export). I'm not well versed in SQL, but I'm thinking to cache the response in a variable.

Comment: Using `INTO` and then `IF EXISTS ()` doesn't work?